# Programmatically disabling all other apps from my own

Tags: android

I want to make android application with the next functions:

1) It  will disable all other apps, during my app works

2) No other app will work even if device is rebooted, until the moment I disable this feature in my app

So, how can i make this? What are the possible ways?

Answer (score 3):

I would be very surprised if anything close to what you want is possible - I'm not saying that you have any malicious intent, but those properties (especially #2) would be key to making a ransomware app.